# Rotate Around Selection not working

Tags: 3d-view

I have Rotate Around Selection selected in Interface > Preferences but although it was working as expected previously, it now does not. Specifically, the view rotates around a specific mesh vertex which seems to have a permenant orange dot on it (same with zoom too):

[image: The specific point which the view always rotates around]

It happens regardless of the mesh selected.

I have tried restarting Blender and reloading the design. It does not happen in other designs.

Any help appreciated as it's very annoying!

Comment: weird because the orange dot must be the object origin but the view should not rotate around it... maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Unforttunately I can't seem to upload the file to that site, it get's stuck on 0%. Instead I have created a new design and appended all the meshes from the old design which seems to have resolved the issue. Should I mark this as resolved? It's not a proper solution but it has fixed it.